# What is the difference of a property and a global constant in uniface

Tags: uniface

I can't understand the difference between a global constant and a property in uniface. When should i use a property? When should i use a global constant?

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest difference between them is scope. While global variables can be used (and reused) across all application components, properties often have scope limitations. See more at: https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/bundle/uniface_104/page/qzg1665702620270.html.